# How to clear logs of a docker container when there is no space left out because of docker logs

Tags: docker

I have a aws instance where I am running a docker container (let it be for any process). The log file in var/log/docker.log is exceeding the storage of the vm. How can I clear the logs and make the storage available in a very clean way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the truncate command to empty the logs

`truncate -s 0 /var/log/docker.log`

There is mention of an old issue with AWS linux instances not rotating docker logs, and a workaround is to use logrotate and update the user data script.
https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-init/issues/119

Answer (score 0):

You should empty the log file.

`cat /dev/null > /var/log/docker.log`